# Elementary question on multilinearity of differential forms

Tags: differential-forms

Have I got this notion of multilinearity right? Say I feed $k$ vectors to a differential $k$-form and out pops a number, 3, for example. If I triple the size of one of the vectors, will the number then be 9? And so on, so halving one of the vectors would give 1.5. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is indeed correct. There is little more to add to this answer due to the concise nature of the question!

Comment: Forgive me for labouring this, but if the original vectors include $v$ and $u$ and I change these to 4$v$ and 3$u$, the answer will then be 36?

Comment: That's correct. This is how multilinearity works indeed.